# Openstack Neutron command workflow

Tags: python, cloud, openstack

I would like to know how neutron dispatches the commands sent by neutron-client. I mean, when you execute a command like:

```
$ neutron agent-list
```

Which python file, on the neutron-server side, should be executed to respond to that command?. I guess that should be a "Agent class" to resolve that request, but I don't know what is the workflow to respond a request.

Thank you.

Comment: You should ask your question here https://launchpad.net/neutron. neutron people are much active there.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenStack Python SDK implements Python bindings to the OpenStack API, which enables you to perform automation tasks in Python by making calls on Python objects rather than making REST calls directly. All OpenStack command-line tools are implemented using the Python SDK.

The neutron commands are in the project [python-neutronclient](https://github.com/openstack/python-neutronclient/blob/master/neutronclient/shell.py) . In the `shell.py` file you can find the command `'agent-list': agent.ListAgent` as well as all other commands.

Comment: the CLI internally translates to python neutron client which in turn uses the rest api. his question can only be answered by neutron rest api developer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go through official neutron guide http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide-cloud/content/ch_networking.html 
 Each components are explained in simple terms along with the commands.

Hope it helps!!